# Can't Understand Deep link and Intent

Tags: html, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I want to use deep link to create a Online-Shop App. **So Hear me out**.
I know I have to use `Intent` and add `<Intent-Filter><Intent-Filter/>` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file but I can't begin to understand how all of it works. There are few packages in **pub.dev** like `flutter_branch_sdk: ^3.4.0` or `receive_sharing_intent: ^1.4.5` but I'm hoping for a complete explanation or some sort of guide here. I appreciate the time you spend reading this in advance.

Here we go:
I have a app that has a `Payment` page. when user clicks on the `Pay Now` Button, He is transferred to a Safe Payment Gateway and interacts with the page. so there are 2 possible scenarios

> 1. He Succeeds in Completing the task and pays for the **CARGO**.

At this point Browser must `Return` to my app and gives me a text/message such as **success** and the app displays the **Payment_Successful_Page**

> 2. He Fails in Completing the task and pays for the **CARGO**

At this point Browser must `Return` to my app and gives me a text/message such as **failure** and the app displays the **Payment_Failed_Page**

---

That said If you know how it works maybe you can answer the questions below. (I have gathered the `code parts` from few documents and guides)

1. What is the `<actvity><actvity/>` do and what does the code below configure?

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTop"
   android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   <intent-filter>
      ...etc categories
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

2. what does the `<action/>` do? How should I use it in app?

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
 <intent-filter />
```

3. how can I work with `<category/>` and What does the code below says?

   what is the tag I should use for my scenario here?

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

4. how can I work with `<data/>` and What does the code below says?

   How to get that text/message I want from the browser?

   How to configure my own website where `"example.com"` is?

   What are `scheme` and `host` here and how should it be written? (with `'http://'` or without)

```
 <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="example.com" />
 <data android:scheme="https" />
 <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
 <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
 <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
 <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="flutterbooksample.com" />
 <data android:scheme="https" />
```

Comment: For the use case you mentioned you don't need deep linking you can use a web view and display that one page right in your app.

Comment: yeah. I noticed that and found some packages like `flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2` to work with. The thing is, a huge part of work is done by the apps original website and I want to keep it that way. So I kinda prefer deep link to Web view.